# Is there a way to filter any node in tree list?

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

Based on https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-data-grid/filter-set-tree-list/#complex-objects, I'd like to know if there's a way for me to filter out data from any node level in tree list?

For eg, https://plnkr.co/edit/GSr5E2rsZRCtk1ip?open=main.js&preview, if I click on the Employment Type and unchecked Permanent, I'd like to only show Contract items

I've this scenario where if I unchecked Great Britain, I'd like to filter out all items where the Location is at Great Britain together with all the sites. Unchecked the site is working fine now, but not for the country.
[image]

This is the partial code
`filter: 'agSetColumnFilter', filterParams: { treeList: true, comparator: this.agTools.locationComparator, treeListPathGetter: (params: ILocations | null) => { switch (this.agTools.locationSwitch(params)) { case ELocationType.Site: { let site = params.site.shortName; let country = params.site.country.name;// + ' (' + params.site.country.code + ')'; let region = params.site.country.region.shortName; if (site === EConstants.Generic) { return [site]; } else { return [region, country, site]; } } case ELocationType.Country: { let country = params.country.name;// + ' (' + params.country.code + ')'; let region = params.country.region.shortName; if (country === EConstants.Generic) { return [country]; } else { return [region, country]; } } case ELocationType.Region: { let region = params.region.shortName; return [region]; } default: { return ['Unknown']; } } }, } as ISetFilterParams<any, ILocations>,`